# How do I return a string with an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, key, return-value

I'm trying to get this homework finished.  I'm stuck on the second one in which I have to return a string with the value of an object key.  I thought I had it right when I used this syntax for the name key.  However, even though the console.log showed the name, the results displayed that I did it wrong.  So I tried it the conventional way and got yet another error.  I'm stuck as to how they want me to do this.  It shouldn't really matter how I do it as long as it produces the same results, but I guess the school doesn't teach that.

```
/**
 * ### Challenge `getName`
 * 
 * @instructions
 * This function takes as its only argument
 * an object containing a `name` property,
 * and return a string that reads `Hello, my name is {name}`,
 * where `{name}` is the name stored in the object.
 * 
 * For example, if we invoke `getName`
 * passing { id: 1, name: 'Leia', email: 'leia@leia.com` } as the argument,
 * the returned value should look like `Hello, my name is Leia`.
*/


function getName(name) {

  var hallo = {

    name: name

  };

 return 'Hello, my name is' + ' ' + hallo.name;
}
```

Comment: You are receiving an object as the parameter, not the name itself. The function will not be called like `getName("Boss")`, but like `getName({ id: 1, name: 'Leia', email: 'leia@leia.com' })`. Now if you check calling your function like that, it will not return the correct result. So, no need to make a _new_ object (`hallo`). Just access the `name` property of the function parameter. Also, please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for the future.

Answer (score 0):

As @Amadan stated, you're receiving an object as a parameter. The parameter should not be `name`, but instead something such as `person`. Then you would return a string and use `person.name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the Object when passing it into your function, only accessing the properties you need for the assignment:

```
let passing = { id: 1, name: 'Leia', email: 'leia@leia.com` }
```

Pass in your desired properties you need to use. Must have same names

```
function getName( { name /*, email, id*/} ) {

 return `Hello my name is ${name}`; //You can also return a console log

} 

let instance1 = getName( passing);
console.log(instance1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone. This worked for me.

function getName(person) {
  return `Hello, my name is ${person.name}`;
}

Comment: Any difference with previous answers?

Answer (score -1):

Following the documentation in the comment, you would want your function to look like this:

```js
/**
 * ### Challenge `getName`
 * 
 * @instructions
 * This function takes as its only argument
 * an object containing a `name` property,
 * and return a string that reads `Hello, my name is {name}`,
 * where `{name}` is the name stored in the object.
 * 
 * For example, if we invoke `getName`
 * passing { id: 1, name: 'Leia', email: 'leia@leia.com` } as the argument,
 * the returned value should look like `Hello, my name is Leia`.
 */


function getName(person) {
  return 'Hello, my name is ' + person.name;
}

const person = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Leia',
  email: 'leia@leia.com'
};

console.log(getName(person));
```

Comment: Actually, the  function already had 'name' as an argument for getname().  I have to use that argument in an object that I make.  This is according to the instructions.  They also said return the string followed by the object value of 'name'.

Comment: Hey, I tried the code and it worked.  Thank you so much.

Comment: “This function takes as it’s only argument an object containing a name property” is what the instructions say. Your function’s argument does not satisfy this instruction — yours has an argument that is a string, the instructions ask for the argument to be an object which would have a property called name. There is a big difference in understanding here if you plan to get an A on this assignment :) the instructions then say to return the string where name is the value of the name property in the object, exactly as i have done.